# import error :No module named 'qiskit_aqua'

Tags: programming, qiskit, quantum-gate

I have an error when I use Quantum SVM kernel algorithm from Qiskit aqua.

This is my code section with imports:

```
from datasets import *
import numpy as np
from qiskit_aqua.utils import split_dataset_to_data_and_labels
from qiskit_aqua.input import svminput
from qiskit_aqua import run_algorithm
from qiskit_aqua.utils import split_dataset_to_data_and_labels
```

And here is the error I obtain:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit_aqua'
```

Comment: Hi @Zeinab Ali! You need to **at least** include the following information in your question: version of `qiskit` installed, how you installed it, version of Python you are running. You can have this information with the commands `python -V` and `python -m pip list`.

Comment: I was going to install qiskit on cluster. I got this error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit.aqua'

Answer (score 4):

If your using the latest qiskit version then it is qiskit.aqua

Comment: Thanks Mr. Nation for your answer, already I did that but every time show new error
such as  ImportError: cannot import name 'QasmQobj' from 'qiskit.qobj'

Answer (score 1):

Please check: https://qiskit.org/documentation/stable/0.28/aqua_tutorials/Qiskit%20Algorithms%20Migration%20Guide.html

As of Qiskit 0.25.0 `qiskit.aqua` has been substituted by several different modules according to the specific application in Optimization, Finance, Chemistry etc...

eg. `qiskit.aqua.operators` has been substituted by `qiskit.opflow` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Qiskit Aqua is being phased out, and its components are being moved to different libraries. You can use the qiskit_machine_learning library.
Check here: https://qiskit.org/documentation/machine-learning/apidocs/qiskit_machine_learning.html