# Unable to import split_dataset_to_data_and_labels and map_label_to_class_name in qiskit

Tags: qiskit, programming

I was using command-:
`from qiskit.aqua.utils import split_dataset_to_data_and_labels, map_label_to_class_name`
but it was giving error-:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 8>()
      6 from qiskit.circuit.library import ZZFeatureMap
      7 from qiskit_machine_learning.algorithms import QSVC
----> 8 from qiskit.aqua.utils import split_dataset_to_data_and_labels, map_label_to_class_name

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit.aqua'
```

I checked [import error :No module named 'qiskit_aqua'](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/6662/import-error-no-module-named-qiskit-aqua) but it was outdated.

I also checked https://qiskit.org/documentation/stable/0.28/aqua_tutorials/Qiskit%20Algorithms%20Migration%20Guide.html but did not found about it.

Comment: `pip install qiskit-aqua`

Comment: @Egretta.Thula I tried but it is giving errors on installation for h5py and python tries to choose different version of h5py and not installs.

Comment: This is a Python-related question. You can post it in Stackoverflow for good answers.

My suggestion: if these two functions are all what you need from Qiskit Aqua, you can copy them from [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/blob/main/qiskit/aqua/utils/dataset_helper.py).

Comment: @Egretta.Thula Ok. But is there any other way to import it as I want to keep my code clean.

Comment: As Qiskit Aqua is deprecated, your code will be cleaner without depending on it.

Comment: @Egretta.Thula Ok and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue, required code needs to be copied and applied in python from-: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/blob/main/qiskit/aqua/utils/dataset_helper.py

This is based on Egretta.Thula's suggestion.